# Cannot get channel updates with MadelineProto

Tags: php, telegram

I have logged into my account as user with Madeline, but when I want to receive channel messages say from @MadelineProto with sample code, I get the following error:

> Error: Call to a member function getMessages() on null in
>   src/telegram_example/index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main}

Code:

```
if (!file_exists('madeline.php')) {
    copy('https://phar.madelineproto.xyz/madeline.php', 'madeline.php');
}
include 'madeline.php';

$MadelineProto = new \danog\MadelineProto\API('session.madeline');
$MadelineProto->start();

$messages_Messages = $MadelineProto->channels->getMessages(['channel' => '@MadelineProto', 'id' => [InputMessage, InputMessage], ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/docs/UPDATES.html to fetch updates, all other methods are prone to flood wait and should not be used for normal update fetching.
Make sure login did not fail by looking at the logs in ULTRA_VERBOSE mode.

Comment: Should I log in in your code as user or bot to do that?

Comment: Either way is OK.